# Display two dynamic plotly and highcharter plots based on condition in a shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny dashboard below in which initially you can see a `selecctinput()`. When the user chooses Return Analysis then a second `selectInput()` is created. For each one of the first two of its choices a different plot should be displayed. The issue is that I need the plot that is displayed to be displayed at the top while now the highcharter plot is displayed at the bottom.

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(highcharter)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("sec","Page",choices=c("Introduction","Return Analysis"),selected = "Introduction"),
    uiOutput("tab")

  ),
  dashboardBody(
    plotlyOutput("plot"),
    highchartOutput("hc2")
  )
)
#server.r
server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$tab<-renderUI({
    if(input$sec=="Introduction"){
      return(NULL)
    }
    else if(input$sec=="Return Analysis"){

      selectInput("tb", "Tabs",choices=c("Monthly Returns","Monthly Returns(Histogram)","Annual Returns"),selected = "Monthly Returns")
    }
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    if(input$sec=="introduction"){
      return(NULL)
    }
    else if(input$tb=="Monthly Returns"){
      plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt)

    }
    else{
      return(NULL)
    }
  })
  output$hc2 <- renderHighchart({
    if(input$sec=="Introduction"){
      return(NULL)
    }
    else if(input$tb=="Monthly Returns(Histogram)"){
      data(diamonds, mpg, package = "ggplot2")

      hchart(mpg, "scatter", hcaes(x = displ, y = hwy, group = class))
    }

    else{
      return(NULL)
    }
  })

  }
```

Comment: If you put `highchartOuptut` before `plotlyOutput`, then the highchart will appear at the top. Is there a particular reason you are using both `plotly` and `highchart` in your app? If you use one package you can have a single `*Output` call to render the two different plots.

Comment: yes I need to do it with plotly and highcharter. Can this be done?

Comment: guess that I would use the same package how would that work?

Comment: If you have a single output container, then the same approach, with an additional `if` statement should work. You are just switching between types of plots, all being created by e.g.,`renderPlotly` and sent to the same `plotlyOutput`.

Comment: ok but it impresses me that there is no solution for 2 packages

Comment: Not saying that there isn't a solution. But you can probably make either of your plots in both of those packages (I say probably, can't be sure of course). So for simplicity it makes sense to use one package and one type of output container.

Comment: I will leave it open and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using both `highchart` and `plotly`. We have a `renderUI` that sends the chart to the UI and a `reactive` that monitors user inputs and generates both the plots and the `*Output` handlers.

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(highcharter)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput(
      "sec",
      "Page",
      choices = c("Introduction", "Return Analysis"),
      selected = "Introduction"
    ),
    uiOutput("tab")
  ),
  dashboardBody(uiOutput("various_plots"))
)

#server.r
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tab <- renderUI({
    if (input$sec == "Return Analysis") {
      selectInput(
        "tb",
        "Tabs",
        choices = c(
          "Monthly Returns",
          "Monthly Returns(Histogram)",
          "Annual Returns"
        ),
        selected = "Monthly Returns"
      )
    }
  })

  what_to_render <- reactive({
    if (req(input$tb) == "Monthly Returns(Histogram)") {
      output$plot2 <- renderHighchart({
        hchart(mpg, "scatter", hcaes(
          x = displ,
          y = hwy,
          group = class
        ))
      })
      x <- highchartOutput("plot2")
    }

    if (req(input$tb) == "Monthly Returns") {
      output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~ mpg, y = ~ wt)
      })
      x <- plotlyOutput("plot1")
    }

    return(x)
  })

  output$various_plots <- renderUI({
    what_to_render()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I aacept it tnx